# SQL server setup and test

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, express

I have some basic experience using sql server 2008 R2 (server management studio).  I was wondering if the express version can be installed and used on a non server computer (os = MS XP).  I have a simple web app that I want to test/practice connecting to the db, and performing simple insert/delete/update commands on a table.  Can this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL Server Express can be installed on any Windows operating system, including the "client" OSes, except Windows CE of course, but that's something else.

You can use SSMS against SQL Server Express too, although some features of SSMS will be disabled becuase the server doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

> Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows
>   Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, Windows XP

Check this:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3743)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does offer SQL express, which probably offers more functionality than you would probably need right now.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Not only would you need MSSQL, you would need to have a current version of IIS installed. Is there a reason you are particularly interested in MSSQL? There are other "package" installations available of PHP/MYSQL which are more simple in setting up such as XAMPP:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-beta.html